# Sublime Text don't build anything

Tags: build, sublimetext2

I used Sublime Text 2 in Ubuntu Linux and worked pretty fine.

Now, when I use it in Windows, i can't build anything. It appears "building" in the status bar in the bottom and then do nothing. I did a trivial test like building a print "hello world" in python build system and nothing happens.

I am missing anything? Btw: the python is in the System Path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is, here are somethings you can try.

**0. Recheck**

Sublime text 2 just calls `python -u $file` on both linux and windows. I would first double check this command works in a new cmd window.

**1. Patch exec.py**

On Windows systems new windows opened by the build process are hidden. This stops GUIs and maybe the python terminal from appearing.

You can disable this patching `Packages\Default\exec.py` by commenting out line 33:

```
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

**2. Indirectly calling python**

Another option is to modify `Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build` so that it calls a bat file which then executes the python file. (this is what I am currently doing for .swf files)

**3. Hardcoding Python path**

Or, this is not ideal, you can try hard coding the python path into the build file like:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Hope one of the above works.

Comment: Hi, so that makes sense now. The problem with build is that it really builds but not run the file :/ Thanks for your explanation. I couldn't find the exec.py in sublime text 2. Where it is?

Comment: @AndréFreitas I've updated the post with the exec.py path. Building does in fact run the file and does the same in windows and linux. If none of the above works I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Hi, the exec.py have a bug in Windows. I need to email sublime text 2. Thanks ;D

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with

```
cmd: ["mongo","<","$file"]
```

and when I changed to

```
cmd: ["mongo $file"]
```

it worked.