# Python Sublime Text Path

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I downloaded sublime text 2 and I have a problem running a code with the language python. Here is my code:

```
def main:
    print "Hello"
main()
```

I get an error when I do ctrl + B:

> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> [cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\Users\Hari\Documents\test.py']]
>
> [dir:  C:\Users\Hari\Documents]
>
> [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon]
>   [Finished]

I am using Windows 8 and I tried to change the environment variables by adding C:\Python27\; or C:\Python26\; or C:\Python33\; or C:\Python2\; or C:\Python2\; to the beginning of the path but it still gives me the same error. Can someone help me?

Comment: I dont see your python path at env variable...

Comment: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'python', u'-u', u'C:\\Users\\Hari\\Documents\\test.py']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Hari\Documents]
[path: C:\Python27\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows

Comment: The same error pops up again.

Comment: See this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/13111706/403810

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Python\Python.sublime-build

Modify (change) content to:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Python27\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

So, change the "C:\Python27\" path part to any path/version of Python that exists in your system.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make sure that changes to environment variables are applied is to reboot Windows.

And if `Sublime Text 2` is started from some Python script using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, then it starts to behave strangely.

Answer (score -1):

delete all the paths for python on your system...and try to install python again,I recommend python27. in the environments add c:/python27.

Comment: Does sublime text 2 automatically download python27 for me or do i have to do it by myself? Also, how do you delete all the paths for python on the system?

Comment: Sublime wont download anything for you so you have to download it by yourself. Yes delete all the python paths on your system and start all over. I use pyDev eclipse plugin its great for python developments I suggest you check it out.

Comment: Could you explain a little more, into your choice.. Why you think it's best etc.. As it is, this is suitable for a comment.

Comment: well i just think it makes everything easier when it comes to python. Its my personal favorite anyway